# how to run a batch file in Node.js with input and get an output

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, batch-file

In `perl` if you need to run a batch file it can be done by following statement.

```
system "tagger.bat < input.txt > output.txt";
```

Here, `tagger.bat` is a batch file, `input.txt` is the input file and `output.txt` is the output file.

I like to know whether it is possible to do it be done in `Node.js`  or not? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a child process. Unline Python, node.js is asynchronous meaning it doesn't wait on the `script.bat` to finish. Instead, it calls functions you define when `script.bat` prints data or exists:

```
// Child process is required to spawn any kind of asynchronous process
var childProcess = require("child_process");
// This line initiates bash
var script_process = childProcess.spawn('/bin/bash',["test.sh"],{env: process.env});
// Echoes any command output 
script_process.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
// Error output
script_process.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
// Process exit
script_process.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Apart from assigning events to the process, you can connect streams `stdin` and `stdout` to other streams. This means other processes, HTTP connections or files, as shown below:

```
// Pipe input and output to files
var fs = require("fs");
var output = fs.createWriteStream("output.txt");
var input =  fs.createReadStream("input.txt");
// Connect process output to file input stream
script_process.stdout.pipe(output);
// Connect data from file to process input
input.pipe(script_process.stdin);
```

Then we just make a test bash script **`test.sh`**:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=`cat -`
echo "Input: $input"
```

And test text input **`input.txt`**:

```
Hello world.
```

After running the `node test.js` we get this in console:

```
stdout: Input: Hello world.

child process exited with code 0
```

And this in **`output.txt`**:

```
Input: Hello world.
```

Procedure on windows will be similar, I just think you can call batch file directly:

```
var script_process = childProcess.spawn('test.bat',[],{env: process.env});
```

Comment: at line number 2 : it is showing unexpected token on var

Comment: Ok, try it now. First try just this: `spawn('test.bat  < input.txt > output.txt');`. If it doesn't create output file, try the streams.

Comment: now it is showing unexpected token at the opening braces.

Comment: @ShvetChakra Ok, I actually tested this on linux and got it to work out of curiosity, hopefully it will help someone else, who can at least copy and paste a script in his IDE.

Comment: thanks for your help but you just broke my confidence, its my first day on Node.js and i have never worked on it but i am learning and i will.

Comment: @ShvetChakra If you're mature enough to write comments as the one above, you're also mature enough to tell me line error. And about that 1 rep user note - you 1 rep guys just ask questions and then do not even cooperate on solution that I started checking user reputation before answering. This question is exception as I started with node last week and I was curious to find the answer.

Comment: var script_process = childProcess.spawn('tagger.bat',[],{env:process.env});
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:118:18)
    at node.js:952:3  // i told you what i was able to figure out

Comment: Well you're using some overlay above Node.js. Try to first create file containing just my script and when it works, connect it to your project. `Unexpected token var` basically means that there's something *before* the script that wasn't properly closed (eg. functionn call).

Comment: There was some path problem. But its working very fine now :) Thank you so much :)